# Non-conventional form for a full conditional

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, jags, bugs

I have a full-conditional of the form :
$$
p(X|...) \propto  \exp(-(aX^2 +bX +c/X)),
$$
All of the other full-conditionals of my model simplify to a simpler form and for a sake of simplicity, I would like to instantiate my model using Jags or WinBugs (which means that I need to explicit a form for $p(X|...)$ and that I cannot use explicitly a Metropolis step for $p(X|)$ (I think)).

Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Could you tell us anything about the likely values of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $X$? For some ranges of these values, this function is very close to Gaussian (but in others it is actually bimodal).

Comment: Is the whole term over $X$ or simply $c$? In the first case, it is an inverse Gaussian distribution.

Comment: whuber: I am investigating for typical values.
Xi'an: I do not understand what you mean. can you please develop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to darrenjw answer, you can use  Metropolis step for your conditional: such modification is called Metropolis-within-Gibbs algorithm. It is perfectly valid. In facto, all yout conditionals can have no-analytical form, instead for each conditional you perform Metropolis algorithm.
WinBUGS does not allow you to specify you algorithm explicitly. You just state the model, and he will do it for you - but not necesserily the best choice will be made.

Comment: I am note sure to know how to implement this part of my model in Jags (I guess it would be the same in WinBugs). Eventually, I need to specify a distribution for X and It seems to me that one are limitated to distribution proposed by the software. Do you agree with that ? I am aware of the one/zero trick but it seems unsatistactory in my case.

Comment: zero-one trick is for sampling distribution (maybe i'm wrong). I think, you can implement any sampling distribution with this trick. Anyway,why do you want force Jags/BUGS to do Gibbs sampling? I do not think that it is possible. You can specify your data model, but not the MCMC algorithm. It selects it according to its own rules. If you want specifically to implement Gibbs sampling, I would suggest to do it in R language or Matlab or any other similar software.

Comment: I must be missing something about Jags (I guess it is the same for BUGS). Let's simply say my model is :

$$ 
p(y_i|X_i=x_i,A=a) \propto  \exp(-(ax_i^2 +ax_i +a/x_i)),
$$
with
$$
X_i \sim U(1,10)
$$

$$
A \sim U(0,10)
$$

I do not know how to infer $p(A,(X_i)|(Y_i))$ in Jags naturally (I thought it is not possible). How can we do ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now I am confused: why do you want sampling a random variable from distribution, which does not depend on that random variable? Did you wanted to write as follows? $$p(X_{i}|a) \propto exp(-(ax_{i}^{2}+ax_{i}+a/x_{i}))$$
In this case, winbugs code for defining this distribution by zero trick can be found here: http://users.aims.ac.za/~mackay/BUGS/Manuals/Tricks.html where $L[i]=-(ax_{i}^{2}+ax_{i}+a/x_{i})$

Comment: Sorry I do not know what i was thinking about but you guess my model! The fact is that the zero-tricks seems to me a very sophisticated and maybe unefficient way to "target a density" (maybe I am wrong) while a simple metropolis step will be quite natural. The one trick is not equivalent to a Metroplis step, is it ?

Comment: No, it is not equivalent to a step of any MCMC method. It is just a way to represent a distribution, that is not available in the software itself. I would recommend you to go with R and program Metropolis-Hastings yourself if you are not satisfied with the zero trick representation of your likelihood. In R it is just a few lines of code to run a MH algorithm.
Regarding efficiency of zero trick - it is not worst than just hardcoding you likelihood by R code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advices. I just wonder what you mean by "Regarding efficiency of zero trick - it is not worst than just hardcoding you likelihood by R code.". On what argument do you state that ?

Comment: When coding your likelihood in R you may code just a log of your distribution (up to some numerical constant), while in zero trick you need one additional step - you calculate log-likelihood and the  add the log of poisson distribution. This additional step does not worsten the whole thing. Of course, assuming your log-likelihood is not very complex.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "This additional step does not worsten"? To my view, "worst and better" is more a question of sampling efficiency than of extra-terms computations. Do you suggest that the **sampling procedure** induced by the zero-trick is as much effective (i.e that one can expect a similar variance of the estimators for a given iteration number) than a Gibbs one or simply than the cost of an iteration is equivalent for both methods  ?

Comment: No, I do not mean efficiency in terms of sampling procedure. I mean  it in terms of time of calculation. I have not said anything about the superiority of zero trick agains a gibbs. Since these are uncomparible things. The first is just a representation of you likelihood while other is method for sampling from that likelihood.

Comment: Of course but the, as I understand it, the one-trick induces a sampling procedure relying on the way winbugs/jags deal with poisson process. I do not know how it deals with but I think it makes sense to compare it with a direct Metropolis update. Do you agree ?

Comment: Zero trick has nothing to do with the way WinBUGS/JAGS works. It is just a mathematical reality of the way, various distributions can be represented by zeros distributed according to poisson distribution and this poisson distribution have your loglikelihood as intensity parameter. The resulting log-likelihood is the same: whether you use zero trick or harcode it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jags or WinBUGS you just describe the model and the software will figure out how to do the sampling. For a non-standard full-conditional such as this, the software will use a Metropolis step rather than a Gibbs step.